# How to access the matched value in the default case of structural pattern matching?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, python-3.10

With Python 3.10's match statement, is it possible to use the value met in the default case?

Or does this need to be assigned a variable before `match` so it can be used in the default case?

```py
match expensive_calculation(argument):
    case 'APPLE':
        value = 'FOO'
    case 'ORANGE':
        value = 'BAR'
    case _:
        raise Exception(
           "Wrong kind of fruit found: " +
           str(expensive_calculation(argument))
           # ^ is it possible to get the default value in this case?
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`as` pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#capturing-matched-sub-patterns):

```
match expensive_calculation(argument):
  case 'APPLE':
    value = 'FOO'
  case 'ORANGE':
    value = 'BAR'
  # Using `as` to assign the wildcard default to `argument_calc`.
  case _ as argument_calc:
    raise Exception(f"Wrong kind of fruit found: {argument_calc!r}")
```

Or, the variable name can be assigned directly:

```
match expensive_calculation(argument):
  case 'APPLE':
    value = 'FOO'
  case 'ORANGE':
    value = 'BAR'
  # Assign the default value to `argument_calc`.
  case argument_calc:
    raise Exception(f"Wrong kind of fruit found: {argument_calc!r}")
```

Comment: why not simply `case argument:`?

Comment: @panda-34 the patch applies to `expensive_calculation(argument)` not argument it's self.

Comment: @ideasman42 There's no runtime difference between `case _ as whatever` and `case whatever`, except `case _ as` for some reason generates two extra superfluous bytecode instructions (in python 3.10).

Comment: @panda-34 OK, I see what you mean, `case argument` is misleading as it overwrites the existing variable name, better use a different name for clarity.